# Datatype long - what does high and low mean?

Tags: json, long-integer

I'm working with an API and at some point I'm getting a `JSON` with an entry like this:

```
cooldown_complete_timestamp_ms: Long { low: 600206158, high: 342, unsigned: false}
```

I dont know how to cope with this data - what does it mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That ain't regular JSON, where the value of an `object` can only be `string`, `number`, `object`, `array`, **`true`**, **`false`** or **`null`**. See http://www.json.org/.

The API you are using must be replying with something which is derived from JSON.

Which API are you programming against?

I'm guessing that the API is trying to emulate/forcing a 64-bit integer, similar to [`LARGE_INTEGER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383713.aspx), a Win32 construct.

The value you are looking at is probably `342 * 2^32 + 600206158`, in other words `1469479021390`.

Comment: i was able to cast it to a date using `.toNumber()` and took this value and `new Date(foo)` it and you're probably right with your assumption! btw I tried `typeof` with this field and it gave me `object`. So I guess its a valid JSON

Answer (score 3):

`high` and `low` in this case designate the higher and lower order bits of the long number.

There's an interesting explanation of high and low order bits [here](https://www.gamedev.net/forums/topic/414290-please-explain-high-and-low-order-bitword-terminology/):

> Now, high/low order refers to the place value of the bits or words. For instance, in base 10, if we have four digits ABCD, the A digit has a place value of thousands, B hundreds, C tens, and D ones. In binary this is similar, except place values grow by powers of 2 - you'd have A eights, B fours, C twos, and D ones.
>
> The high-order bit is the bit with the highest place value in a given block of bits. This may be a byte, word, dword, or whatever. The high-order word is the word containing the high-order bit; at least two words are required for this to make sense. Low order is similar, but using the least-significant place value instead.

Let's assume our Long has 64 bits. `low` would be the base 10 representation of the 32 lower order bits (typically on the right) whereas `high` would be the base 10 representation of the 32 higher order bits (typically on the left).

That specific Long representation seems to originate from the [Long](https://www.npmjs.com/package/long) library, a tool that helps tp represent long numbers in javascript.

Reading the source on [GitHub](https://github.com/dcodeIO/long.js/blob/master/src/long.js#L29) is a treasure of insight on why this representation is chosen, but most importantly:

```
// The internal representation of a long is the two given signed, 32-bit values.
// We use 32-bit pieces because these are the size of integers on which
// Javascript performs bit-operations.  For operations like addition and
// multiplication, we split each number into 16 bit pieces, which can easily be
// multiplied within Javascript's floating-point representation without overflow
// or change in sign.
```

---

You were able to interact with the value with `toNumber` because they've [implemented it](https://github.com/dcodeIO/long.js/blob/088e44e5e3343ef967698565678384fa474b003b/index.js#L485-L488) in the library.